# R "random" distributions

Tags: r, random

I have been seeing series of generated data with too much similarity between near entries from `runif`

Here is a short session from RStudio

```
1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
```

This will give us five "randomly" distributed entries between (-1,1) .. well .. so I had understood.. The reality is different:

```
> 1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
[1] -0.1534864 -0.3069729 -0.4604593 -0.6139458 -0.7674322
> 1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
[1] 0.01084729 0.02169457 0.03254186 0.04338915 0.05423643
> 1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
[1] -0.003854265 -0.007708529 -0.011562794 -0.015417058 -0.019271323
> 1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
[1] -0.8809448 -1.7618896 -2.6428343 -3.5237791 -4.4047239
> 1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
[1] -0.768577 -1.537154 -2.305731 -3.074308 -3.842885
> 1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
[1] 0.03255907 0.06511815 0.09767722 0.13023629 0.16279537
```

Notice:

- the first series range is (-.767,-.15)
- the second series range is (.01,.05)
- the third series range is (-.0038,-.019)

etc. Clearly these are not truly `random` series.  So:

- what **are** these series representing
- how do we get more realistic randomly distributed series.

Comment: How come you aren't just using `runif(5,-1,1)`? That gives (optically) better results. Though it should not matter. I think you have raised a good question

Comment: Oh, I think I see.... It is multipying by the values.

Comment: Range is -5 to 5, no?

Comment: Don't think this is a SO question, especially since there's no way to objectively define "realistic" random in any programming language. Check `?Random` for available methods for adjusting .Random.seed

Comment: I know, it took me a minute or two to catch on. I fell in the same mental trap that he did.

Comment: This is a SO question because by "realistic" he means "not buggy", not in the philosophical sense of real random numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
1:5 * runif(1,-1,1)
```

is the same as

```
   x <- runif(1,-1,1)
   1*x, 2*x, ... 5*x
```

Which is not what you want as only 1 random number is ever generated, and then it is scaled successively.

What you want is:

```
   runif(5,-1,1)
```

Comment: Yep. If you look at `plot(c(1:100) * runif(1,-1,1))` the only random thing is the slope ;-)

Comment: Ha. I deleted the comment. But yeah, I was wondering why the plots were so straight. The question does have a tricky aspect.

Comment: ok I was thinking of 1:5 as indices not actual values in a sequence.